# straight distance between points on concentric circles

Tags: circles

$C_1$ and $C_2$ are concentric circles, with radii $R_1$ and $R_2$, $R_1$ being shorter. Point "$P_1$" on $C_1$, and Point "$P_2$" on $C_2$. The radii to the points form an unknown angle, but $\text{Arc}_1$ (the arc length on $C_1$) is known. How to calculate the $P_1$ to $P_2$ distance? Thanks[image: distance in red?]

I see related posts, but not clear how to convert to my problem.
([solving for spiral distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727504/calculate-distance-between-two-points-on-concentric-circles), or
[given the skew angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621150/length-of-line-between-concentric-circles-based-on-skew-of-line-to-circles))

Comment: When you say the arclength on $c_1$ is known, are you talking about the arc between $R-1$ and $R_2$ in the figure?

Comment: Correct, thanks. This is actually a geography application, to determine the direct distance between points with different x,y,z coordinates. I'm getting Arc length (at sea level) from Vincenty's formulae, and calculating Earth radii from here: ([link] (https://rechneronline.de/earth-radius/))

Comment: The arc length in radians is the same as the angle between $R_1$ and $R_2$.  Now apply the law of cosines.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan. If not too much bother, what would that formula look like in practice?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: ok, i see it, duh. Since I have $R_1$ and $R_2$, and the angle (in radians), then i just need to convert radians to degrees and then solve the triangle. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite right, but I've found the missing piece: "Arc Length" = "Radius" x "Angle in Radians". *Now* I can solve with law of cosines. :-)